# implementing shell sort for linked lists?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement shell sort on singly-linked lists. What I have tried to do is get the respective elements based on the `inc` value and sort them. However, I'm only familiar with shell sort implementation on arrays and not linked lists. Any help is appreciated.

```
struct node
  { int data;
    struct node *next;
  };                                                                                                                                

typedef struct node n;

void add(int a);
void shellsort(int size);
void display();
void moveptr(n*a, int distance);

n* head=NULL;

void main()
  { int i,x,size;
    printf("How many elements do you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter the data: ");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      { scanf("%d",&x);
        add(x);
      }
     
    printf("List currently is: ");
    display();
    shellsort(size);
    printf("\nafter sorting list is: ");
    display();
  }

void add(int a)
  { n *temp = (n*)malloc(sizeof(n));
    temp->data=a;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
  } 

void display()
 { n* temp=head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
     { printf("%d-->",temp->data);
          temp=temp->next;
      }
  }

void moveptr(n *ptr, int distance) // this moves a temp pointer to required location
  { int i=0;
    while(i<distance)
       {
           ptr=ptr->next;
           i=i+1;
       }   
  }

void shellsort(int size)
  { int i,j,temp,inc=size/2;
    n *a=head,*b=head;
    do{
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
          { 
            for(j=i+inc;j<size;j+=inc)
             { b=head;
               moveptr(b,j);
               if(a->data > b->data)
                 { temp=b->data;
                   b->data=a->data;
                   a->data=temp;
                 }
             }
             a=a->next;
            }
        inc=inc/2;
     }while(inc>=1);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think a shell sort on a linked list would be a good idea?  It seems an odd requirement.  A shell sort is pretty much designed for sorting an array only; it uses variable gaps between the elements it compares in the array, and that becomes abysmally slow (at best) if you have to step through a linked list instead of indexing the array.  You'd probably need to convert the list into an array and then sort the array and convert the result back into a linked list.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you. Maybe I should ask my prof. about his reasoning.

Comment: I don't think that algorithm exists at all. Shell sort requires fast-seeking datastructures.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using shell sort:

- allocate an array of pointers to list items,
- initialize this array to point to the individual items in the list
- sort the array using shell sort
- relink the list in the order of the array elements
- free the list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shellsort needs data structure which can easily finds the entries of gap and swap them.
2. It depends on if you want to implement singly or double linked list.

But I would think twice if linked list is a good idea because of space complexity and this sort needs to be (or at least it is a good idea to be **in-place** — no need tons of pointers for swaps).

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65063511/17726418) above is not a correct way to implement it, you should not implement a linked list with an array because of easy manipulation.